# How to automatically click "read more" in the WeChat message using Appium(java)

Tags: java, appium

When I'm doing automation with WeChat using appium + eclipse, I found that i cannot locate the `Read more` link. All the content is contained by a `FrameLayout`, but all the elements cannot be chosen. I tried to click the "read more" link by using `appdriver.tap(1, x, y, 1)` command, the x and y are the coordinates of the "read more" link, but it didn't work. Is there any good idea? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eitnY.png)

Comment: looking at the image I believe you've got to go deeper in the hierarchy to select the element `Read More`

Comment: Thanks reply. There's no element "Read more" in the hierarchy. That's my headache.

Comment: is it using the webview? Try to use chrome inspect

Comment: Thanks, but the test require the action performed inside WeChat not inside chrome browser. all the links and picture are in the widget "com.tencent.smtt.webkit.WebView".

Comment: Thanks all. i figured it out, add the wait time so the tap() function can work.

Comment: You should check might be that element comes under Webview, if yes then you need to enable webview debugger first at back-end then Appium can identify,

Comment: Using Coordinates might not be a good idea to use. This would get change on different devices.

Comment: @Fangfang probably of you could select the `Read More` option in the inspector and share the entire hierarchy would be great.

Comment: @Fangfang also to the point that "all the links are in the widget `Webkit`", you should prefer switching the context to WebView and then performing actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
use driver.tap(1, yourelement, 1000) 
driver.tap(int finger, WebElement, int duration) //this is the function i use above
```

there is one more function and that is

```
driver.tap(int finger, int x,int y, int duration)
```

if this does not help, u can use touchaction tap like this :

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.tap(int x, int y).release().perform();
```

Comment: driver.tap(int finger, int x,int y, int duration)  worked for me. Thanks for the summary.